# is it possible to use object inside flask app

Tags: python, flask

I wanna do a POST request on an flask app like this:

```
    def create_app():
        app = Flask(__name__)

        with app.app_context():
            c = Config('cfg.cfg')
            abc = Abc(c)

        return app

    app = create_app()

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def handle_webhook():
    return abc.handle_incoming_hook(request)
```

but is gives me error: `abc is undefined`.
Is there anything I was missing?

Comment: Is it `abc is undefined` or `Abc is undefined`? I can't see the definition of `Abc`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable abc is being declared outside of the scope of your handle_webhook function. You will either need to pass abc in to the handle_webhook function, or declare it within the scope of the handle_webhook function.